# Как запустить setInterval только один раз?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, settimeout

Есть куча вопросов с таким названием, но они немного мне не подходят. У меня есть скрипт, который проверяет есть ли блок в поле видимости окна браузера. И есть число, которое я хочу анимировать, рост температуры от 0 до 60.
я написал вот такой скрипт для этого

```js
function checkTempWidth() {
    if (!animTemp) {

    } else {
        let startTemp = 0;
        let endTemp = 60;
        let el = animTemp;
        function interval() {
            if (startTemp !== endTemp) {
                startTemp++;
                animTemp.innerHTML = `${startTemp}`;
            } else {
                startTemp = endTemp;
            }
            return startTemp
        }
        let spaceBellow = window.innerHeight - el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom + el.offsetHeight;
        let topDistance = el.getBoundingClientRect().top + el.offsetHeight;
        // console.log(topDistance + 'topDistacne');
        if (60 < spaceBellow && topDistance > 0) {

                setInterval(interval, 100);

        } else {

        }

    }
}
```

И если при перезагрузке все хорошо и он срабатывает один раз, то если скролить страницу, когда блок в зоне видимости, он запускает кучу этих интервалов
Как бы это исправить? Я хочу что бы когда блок появился в окне браузера, запустился этот скрипт и все, больше не нужно. Спасибо.
Если знаете как это сделать на jQ, то ок, только расшифруйте что и как там

Comment: вот я сделал на кодпене свой пример https://codepen.io/jukachu/pen/yLaPygY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let timer;
function checkTempWidth() {

  function interval() {
    if (startTemp !== endTemp) {
      startTemp++;
      animTemp.innerHTML = `${startTemp}`;
    } else {
      timer = clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }
  ...

    if (!timer)
      timer = setInterval(interval, 100);
```

Comment: с setTimeout число увеличивается только один раз, если вывести переменную `startTemp` вне функции, то просто будет +1 при каждом ивенте скролла

Comment: Спасибо огромное, это работает)

Comment: @JukaChu Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.